# pyqt5 QpushButton not working

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qpushbutton

I have this GUI written in python and utilizing PYQT5. I have a functioning version, but I now want to add a QpushButton that executes a method called add_Bladebox. This method adds a doublespinbox to the gui. The method works fine when I call it as part of the code, but when I try to execute it via the QpushButton, nothing happens. I know that without a loop, I could only ever do it once anyway(no position change implemented), but I can add that feature later. So any suggestion as to why it's not working is well appreciated.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QSizePolicy,

                       QDoubleSpinBox, QLabel, QCheckBox, QMainWindow, 
QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

# Mark: QGridlayout importoitu, muttei käytetty

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as F 
igureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as 
NavigationToolbar


class MainWindow(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.initUI()

    # Geometry of main window:
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 1000)
    self.setWindowTitle('Simulation')


    # Set canvas:   
    self.m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=10)
    self.m.move(0,0)


    # Simulate button:
    sim = QPushButton('Simulate', self)
    sim.clicked.connect(self.simulate)
    sim.resize(sim.sizeHint())
    sim.move(550, 700)

    # Quit button:
    qbtn = QPushButton('Quit', self)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
    qbtn.move(800, 700)

    # Input box for x1:
    self.x1 = self.inputBox(800,80,10.0,0.01,0.2,2)
    self.x1_label = self.label(800,60,"x1")


    # Checkbox for sending data via email:
    self.send_box = QCheckBox('Send data’, self)
    self.send_box.move(550, 600)
    self.send_box.toggle()


    # Button for adding input boxes
    blade_button = QPushButton('Add', self)
    # THE PROBLEM IS THE NEXT LINE AS FAR AS I UNDERSTAND
    blade_button.clicked.connect(self.add_Bladebox)

   self.show()

# Method executes simulation:
def simulate(self):

    # TODO Read parameter values. Look explanations of parameters from 
simu_func.py



# Method for input box:
def inputBox(self, left, top, maxvalue, step, default,decimals):
    box = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
    box.move(left,top)
    box.setDecimals(decimals)
    box.setMaximum(maxvalue)
    box.setSingleStep(step)
    box.setProperty("value", default)
    box.resize(box.sizeHint())
    return box


# Method for label:
def label(self, left, top, text):
    lbl = QLabel(self)
    lbl.setText(text)
    lbl.resize(lbl.sizeHint())
    lbl.move(left,top)
    return lbl

# Method for adding blade boxes
def add_Bladebox(self):
    left=900
    top=500
    maxvalue=3
    step=1
    default=0
    decimals=1
    blade_box = self.inputBox(left, top, maxvalue, step, default, decimals)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Of what? The GUI that opens up?

Comment: Something that people can copy paste and run to reproduce the problem, as explained on the page.